# Need I specify the assemblyIdentity (Web.config)?

Tags: asp.net

I can create and build a new ASP.NET project and use Razor and more technologies only specifying the Razor version and 0 assemblyIdentities. I've downloaded MVC5 and my empty web project has been modified, adding assemblyIdentites in Web.config. I'm using more technologies/references and they aren't specified in Web.config with assemblyIdentity. Razor for example.

Then, will use my web the latest technologies/DLLs installed in the server if I don't specify it with assemblyIdentity? Or why VS adds this to Web.config?

This is my Web.config modified when I updated to MVC5:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>

<!-- NEW
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
-->

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056499/what-is-the-meaning-reason-for-the-generated-entries-in-web-configconfiguration). The post has an explanation regarding what the section of the web config file is trying to accomplish.

Comment: The question is why some technologies have no references in Web.config (as the Razor version), and others yes.